# Can data in Azure SQL database be accessed from Corda nodes deployed in Azure?

Tags: azure, corda

We are working on a POC in Azure IoT platform that would also make use of Corda nodes (deployed in Azure).

We want to know whether corda nodes (deployed in Azure) can query Azure SQL database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Corda Enterprise edition has been tested with Azure SQL DB and it works without problems. These 2 links should be helpful to learn more:

- https://docs.corda.r3.com/database-management.html
- https://docs.corda.r3.com/platform-support-matrix.html